# Classic Space part? near-triangle with 2x6 on one end and 1x2 on the other and a lot of empty space between

Tags: part-identification, space

Is this a classic space part? Found in a box of old LEGO.

[image: near-triangle with 2x6 on one end and 1x2 on the other]

[image: near-triangle with 2x6 on one end and 1x2 on the other]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is

[Part #30036: Wedge, Plate 8 x 6 x 2/3 with Grille](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30036#T=C)

In White it appears in two Exploriens sets

- [6856: Planetary Decoder](https://brickset.com/sets/6856-1/Planetary-Decoder)

and

- [6982: Explorien Starship](https://brickset.com/sets/6982-1/Explorien-Starship)

Comment: You have correctly identified the part, however the question was a little different. I suppose the answer is "no"?